# How to tell that a free type definition is good?

Tags: logic, definition, recursion, type-theory

Consider the following free type definition:

$\text{Tree} := \text{leaf}\langle\!\langle\mathbb{N}\rangle\!\rangle\ |\ \text{branch}\langle\!\langle\text{Tree}\times\text{Tree}\rangle\!\rangle$

How can I tell, by looking at this definition, that there exists a set, $T$, and two injective functions, $l:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow T$, and $b:(T\times T)\rightarrow T$, such that

1. $\text{Rng}(l)\cap\text{Rng}(b) = \emptyset$.
2. Every $S \subseteq T$, such that $\text{Rng}(l) \subseteq S$, and such that $b[S\times S] \subseteq S$, coincides with $T$.

More generally, given a free type definition, how can I tell that there is a set and functions that are consistent with the definition?

Where can I read more about this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working in set theory, we can start by defining some concrete implementations of $l$ and $b$:
$$ l(n) = \langle 0,n\rangle \qquad\qquad b(x,y) = \langle 1,\langle x,y\rangle\rangle $$
So far these are *class functions* -- we have not defined the domain of $b$ yet, but it is clear that *a priori* these expressions make sense for any domains whatsoever, and that their ranges will always be disjoint.

Now recursively define a sequence of sets $T_n$ by
$$ \begin{align} T_0 ={}& \varnothing \\
T_{n+1} ={}& (\text{range of $l$ on $\mathbb N$}) \cup (\text{range of $r$ on $T_n\times T_n$}) \end{align} $$
and finally, using the axioms of replacement and union, set
$$ T = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} T_n $$

*Now* you can define $l$ and $r$ to have domains $\mathbb N$ and $T\times T$, and it is then straightforward to prove that $T$ has the properties you've listed.

---

Note that how this construction is derived completely mechanically from the original definition and can be easily generalized to other similar definitions. So you don't need to "look at the definition" particularly close to tell that there's a set that satisfies it, because *every* such definition can be run through the above procedure.

What makes this work is that all the set operations are *increasing*, such that if you apply them to a superset of what you had before, the result will be a superset of the result before. This holds for power sets, cartesian products, sequences, etc. -- but *not* for function spaces, because $X^{\{1,2,3\}}$ is not a superset of $X^{\{1,2\}}$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in a more straight-forward answer to the general question. One that would enable me, as I mentioned in my question, to read the answer off the free type definition. I know that such an answer exists, because a textbook I'm reading, namely Woodcock and Davies' "Using Z" hints at it in section 10.5 "Consistency": "it is enough to know that any construction involving only Cartesian products and finite power sets is finitary, and that any free type def- inition that uses only finitary constructions will be consistent." Unfortunately, the textbook offers no references.

Comment: @EvanAad: I'm afraid that it is unclear to me what the answer you want to "read off" is.

Comment: I want to know what set operations (e.g. Cartesian product, function formation, powerset) I can use on the right hand side of the free type definition that would ensure that the definition is consistent in the sense explained in my original question.

Comment: Will your construction work when there are no constants? I feel like, if there weren't any constants, then $T_1 = b[T_0\times T_0] = b[\emptyset\times\emptyset] = b[\emptyset] = \emptyset = T_0$, and therefore $T_n = \emptyset$ for every $n$, which would imply that $T = \emptyset$.

Comment: However, there's an example in Woodcock and Davies' textbook (example 10.5 on p. 138) where the free type definition is $\text{SequenceTree} := \text{tree}\langle\!\langle\mathbb{N}\times \text{seq}\ \text{SequenceTree}\rangle\!\rangle$, and they claim that the following is a typical element of the resulting set: $(1, \langle(2, \langle\rangle), (3, \langle\rangle), (4, \langle(2, \langle\rangle)\rangle)\rangle)$.

Comment: By the way, $\text{seq}\ X$ is the set of finite sequences, whose elements are member of the set $X$.

Comment: @EvanAad: Indeed a (finite) binary tree with only nodes and no leaves can't exist so your first example produces the empty set. For your SequenceTree: in the first step of the construction you would have $\mathbb N\times\operatorname{seq}\varnothing$, which is not empty (the second operatnd contains the empty sequence!) so you do get started.

Comment: @EvanAad: I've added a paragraph that attempts to answer the "which set operations". I'm somewhat mystified what the role of "finitary" in your quote is, but I suspect the author wants to argue that the final set $T$ is "finitary" (whatever that means to him) if only the parameters (such as $\mathbb N$) is.

Comment: I've written an answer, where I give meaning to the term "finitary" (generalized from a textbook that I cite in my answer), and where I give a rich (though not necessarily exhaustive) list of set operators that a free datatype constructed exclusively using them is guaranteed to be consistent.